# Cotangent bundle of symmetric space is symmetric space?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group. Then a symmetric space for $G$ is a homogeneous space $G/H$ where the stabilizer $H$ of a typical point is an open subgroup of the fixed point set of an involution involution $σ$ in $Aut(G)$. Thus $σ$ is an automorphism of $G$ with $σ^2 = id$ and $H$ is an open subgroup of the set
$G^\sigma=\{ g\in G: \sigma(g) = g\}.$

> Now let $G/H$ be symmetric space then $T^*(G/H)\cong G^{\mathbb
>  C}/H^{\mathbb C}$ is symmetric space?. Where $G^{\mathbb
>  C}$ means complexification of lie group $G$

Comment: $T^*(S^2)$ is not diffeomorphic to any symmetric space.

Comment: thanks a lot for nice comment, but can you explain more why?

Comment: de Rham decomposition: Every simply-connected symmetric  space is isometric to a product of compact symmetric spaces, Euclidean spaces and symmetric spaces of noncompact type. In this example, the manifold does not split topologically as a product of $S^2$ and $R^2$ (why?).

Comment: Helgason in his book said that if $\frak g/\frak h$ is symmetric then $\frak g^{\mathbb C}/\frak h^{\mathbb C}$ is symmetric. So  $G^{\mathbb
 C}/H^{\mathbb C}$ is symmetric , where is the point?

Comment: My guess is that you are misreading what Helgason said.  What you wrote is a vector space (quotient of two Lie algebras); of course, it admits a flat metric which is symmetric. This has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: In general $G^{\mathbb  C}/H^{\mathbb C}$ known as spherical spaces by Cartan theorem, and sperical spaces are not symmetric in general, but the inverse is correct

Comment: I think Misha means Riemannian symmetric spaces, whereas Hassan Jolany means general symmetric spaces, hence part of the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. See this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1543 (Introduction, and section 4.2 page 14). The basic ideas are that

- if $M$ is a symmetric space, then $TM$ has a canonical structure of symmetric space (whatever the way you realize your symmetric space, apply the tangent functor to it);
- the duality of vector bundles extends to a duality of "symmetric bundles" as defined in the paper (i.e., vector bundles in the category of symmetric spaces): the dual vector bundle of a symmetric bundle inherits a structure of symmetric space which makes it a symmetric bundle.

Hence, $T^*M$ inherits a canonical structure of symmetric space from that of $TM$.